# equation $f(x,y)=0$ can be solved for $y$ in terms of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation $f(x,y)=0$ can be solved for $y$ in terms of $x$.

What does this expression mean? Sorry for such type of question because English is not my native.

Comment: It means you can express $y$ in $x$. For example, $2x+y^2=1$ can be solved as $y=\pm\sqrt{1-2x}$. You get $y$ on one side of the equation and something with only $x$ (no $y$'s) on the other side.

Comment: @vrugtehagel, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

It means that there exists a function $g$ such that

$$f(x,g(x)) = 0$$

i.e. that for $y = g(x)$ the equation $f(x,y) = 0$ is true. An example would be

$$f(x,y) = 2\sin(x) - 3y = 0$$

Then,
$$y = \frac{2}{3} \sin(x) = g(x)$$